# How to test for how far away an object is from another Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance

So I am trying to make a boss for my game that shoots bullets, but currently I can't get the bullets to fire when the main player is close to it. Here is my code so far:

```
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;




// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
   
    if()
    {
        Shoot();
    }

  
    
       
       
    
}

void Shoot()
{
    // shooting logic

    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);


}
```

}

Can I have some help please? Thanks!

Comment: Taking the difference between 2 vectors will give you a direction (another Vector3).  Vector3 has a magnitude property which is the length of the vector. [Vector3.magnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally depends what `check` means for you.

For **get** the distance of two objects there is [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)

```
var distance = Vector3.Distance(objA.transform.position, objB.transform.position);
```

which basically equals using [`Vector3.magnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html)

```
var distance = (objB.transform.position - objB.transform.position).magnitude;
```

**However**, if your question is rather **compare** the distance to something else it is often slightly more efficient using [`Vector3.sqrMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html) instead like e.g.

```
private const float thresholdSqr = someDistance * someDistance;
```

and

```
var distanceSqr = (objB.transform.position - objB.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
if(distanceSqr <= thresholdSqr)
{
    ...
}
```